# Apache Velocity templating: get first element of java.util.Set

Tags: java, velocity, templating-engine

I am looking for a way to get the first element of `java.util.Set` in [velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/) templating engine. Can anyone suggest?

Comment: "First"? `Set` has no concept of an order to its elements.

Comment: my bad, it makes sens. strictly speaking, talking about the "first element of a Set" doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you can get a (random*) element with

```
$var.iterator().next()
```

But `Set`s do not have any order between their elements, so there's no first element.

*Random, like it depends on the set's implementation.
In some cases (for example, when it's a `SortedSet`), the given Iterator will give back the elements in some order. See the `SortedSet`'s [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html):

> The set's iterator will traverse the set in ascending element order.

But in this case, nothing guarantees, that the Set's implementation won't change sometime, so if we're talking about a general `Set`, you should not depend on this.

If we're talking about a `SortedSet`, you should use the `first()` method, instead:

```
$var.first()
```

Comment: **Some** Java sets do have a natural ordering that is reflected in the iterator() method, so this might be useful. For example, [java.utll.TreeSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#iterator--) "Returns an iterator over the elements in this set in ascending order."

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: yeah, but if it's a `TreeSet` (if it's any subclass of `SortedSet`), then it has a `first()` method. But, if the given variable's static type just `Set`, then anybody can change the dinamyc type of the set - and i would not write anything based on some theory (the current implementation is `TreeSet` and...) - I did want to express this, by using the word "random".